# Question on mixed voice (with audio sample)

Tags: voice

So i had been working o my mixed voice for a while but to develop the proper balance is very hard sometimes especially when i was tired or not having enough sleep. Another issue is that the tonal quality. From my understanding, mixed voice tonal quality should not sound too distinct from the chest voice right? Sometimes, I noticed that sometimes my mixed voice sounds very different from my chest, but it depends on the song. I mix around G4, but there are some songs that I had to mix earlier around F#4 or F4 and that was when the huge change in tonal quality happened. So when I mixed at F4 or F#4, the sound will be very different from the lower notes sometime it sounded weak, perhaps mixing in the lower notes require more support right? Because sometimes, depends on the consonant/vowel, my voice will strain when I sing up to F#4. Please correct me I was mistaken on my understanding.

Anyways this song is a good example the issues I mentioned earlier because I had to sing lots of F#4 and G#4 which was around where my break started. So, what do you think on the notes I sung around F#4s and G#4s? Did they sounded weak and if yes should I mix higher?

Link : http://picosong.com/WFLc/

Answer (score 1):

Have you used some melodyne or autotune on your recording? There are some parts where the pitch is kind of weird.

My first advice is: focus on staying in tune. There are some parts that you understand, so don't worry if you have to "mix" in certain note or the other one. Just keep practising that "mix" (although I wouldn't call it Mixed Voice). Also, keep that support, sometimes it seems that you relax it and you start to sound less closed.

If you want to sound with more body and not that weak in certain notes try simply opening your jaw so that your color is not that light. For me, I start "mixing" as you call it, way before that. And I go to reinforced falsetto depending on the passage, from F#4 and up.

Depends on the consonant your voice wants to strain, because you're closing in certain part of your mouth/throat. But keep doing vowel exercises and then put a consonant before them to **keep working for your vowels** instead of for your consonants.